# How to tell which row number is clicked in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, dom-events

I have a table like the following:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When a user clicks on the table, how can I get the index of this row (`tr` element)?

For example, when I click on the first `tr` (with `1`s in the above table), it should pick it up and return `1`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This would get you the index of the clicked row, starting with one:

```js
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thetable">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to return the number stored in that first cell of each row:

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
  var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  alert('You clicked ' + row);
});
```

Comment: Neither of those worked for me. No response when I clicked on the table, didn't enter the function.

Comment: @CashCow: Old answer, old jQuery, etc. First, you should use `on` now: `$('#thetable tr').on('click', function () {...})`. And perhaps some or all of the table is loaded dynamically, in which case you might try binding to an element you know is present when the DOM is ready, like `document`: `$(document).on('click', '#thetable tr', function () {...})`.

Answer (score 25):

A better approach would be to delegate the event, which means catching it as it bubbles to the parent node.

### delegation - overview

This solution is both more robust and efficient.

It allows the event to be handled even if more rows are dynamically added to the table later, and also results in attaching a single event handler to the parent node (`table` element), instead of one for each child node (`tr` element).

Assuming that the OP's example is a simplified one, the table's structure can be more complex, for example:

```
<table id="indexedTable">
    ...
    <tr>
        <td><p>1</p></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><p>3</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Therefore, a simplistic approach such as getting `e.target.parentElement` will not work, as clicking the internal `<p>` and clicking the center `<td>` will produce different results.

Using delegation normalizes the event handling, only assuming that there are no nested tables.

### implementation

Both of the following snippets are equivalent:

```
$("#indexedTable").delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).index() + 1);
});

$("#indexedTable").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).index() + 1);
});
```

They attach a listener to `table` element and handle any event that bubbles from the table rows. The current API is the `on` method and the `delegate` method is legacy API (and actually calls `on` behind the scenes).

Note that the order of parameters to both functions is different.

### example

A comparison between direct handler attachment and delegation is available below or on jsFiddle:

```js
$("#table-delegate").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  var idx = $(e.currentTarget).index() + 1;
  $("#delegation-idx").text(idx);  
  console.log('delegated', idx);
});

$("#table-direct tr").on("click", function(e) {
  var idx = $(e.currentTarget).index() + 1;
  $("#direct-idx").text(idx);
  console.log('direct', idx);
});

$('[data-action=add-row]').click(function(e) {
  var id = e.target.dataset.table;
  $('#' + id + ' tbody')
    .append($('<tr><td>extra</td><td>extra</td><td>extra</td></tr>')[0])
});
```

```css
tr:hover{
    background:#ddd;
}

button.add-row {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<h1>Event handling test</h1>
<p>Add rows to both tables and see the difference in handling.</p>
<p>Event delegation attaches a single event listener and events related to newly added children are caught.</p>
<p>Direct event handling attaches an event handler to each child, where children added after the inital handler attachment don't have a handler attached to them, and therefore their indices won't be logged to console.</p>
<h2>Delegation</h2>
<p><span>row index: </span><span id="delegation-idx">unknown</span></p>
<button class="add-row" data-action="add-row" data-table="table-delegate">Add row to delegation</button>
<table id="table-delegate" class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<h2>Direct attachment</h2>
<p><span>row index: </span><span id="direct-idx">unknown</span></p>
<button class="add-row" data-action="add-row" data-table="table-direct">Add row to direct</button>
<table id="table-direct" class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td>normal</td>
        <td><p>nested</p></td>
    </tr>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/SssdJ/).

P.S:

If you do have nested tables (or, in the general case, wish to delegate to elements with specific depth), you can use [this suggestion from the jQuery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6696#comment:11).

Comment: Tx. It occurred to me that it must be better to make the table handle this rather than the row.  Most of the other answers seem not to be answering the OP's question: how to get the *table* to do this...

Answer (score 20):

A simple and jQuery free solution:

```
document.querySelector('#elitable').onclick = function(ev) {
   // ev.target <== td element
   // ev.target.parentElement <== tr
   var index = ev.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
}
```

**Bonus:** It works even if the rows are added/removed dynamically

Answer (score 19):

You can use `object.rowIndex` property which has an index starting at 0.

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    alert (this.rowIndex);
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fnRt/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
 alert( $('tr').index(this) );
});
```

For first `tr`, it alerts 0. If you want to alert 1, you can add 1 to index.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases we could have a couple of tables, and then we need to detect click just for particular table. My solution is this:

```
<table id="elitable" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
 <td>100</td><td>AAA</td><td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>200</td><td>BBB</td><td>bbb</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<td>300</td><td>CCC</td><td>ccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>


    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#elitable tr").click(function(){
        alert (this.rowIndex);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tnpx1py1/)**

Comment: Another one with this solution. When I try it, it never enters the method.