# How to find out the selected row of an html table

Tags: asp.net

I have made a html table in asp.net. The user clicks on a row and the corresponding page for that record is opened. How do i know which row of the table has the user selected?

Comment: Can you post some code so I can review it in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example tr').click(function() {
         alert('clicked');
    });

});
```

[How to tell which row number is clicked in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524661/jquery-which-row-number-is-clicked-in-table)

without jquery

[Adding an onclick event to a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207939/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-table-row)

http://jsbin.com/ivobe

Comment: edited. example with pure js. But for the record jquery is worth learning

Comment: actually what i want to do is to click on a row and open page with that records details. so i suppose i will have to save the details in a session variable? and how do i go to the next page using your above code?

Comment: open in new window with js, pass it with querystring

Answer (score 0):

try to set custom attribute of id to row(html) by assinging database id value to it. 
by clicking on that row , you can get access that custom attribute by $(this).attr('your_custom_attr') and you can use that value to make ajax GET call.