# get row number on row click in jQuery for bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery

As easy as it sounds but I am stuck in retrieving the `row number` of the current clicked/selected row.

I have tried the following so far.
I am using `bootstrap table` just in case you want to know.

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {

     //var row_num = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) + 1;

     //var row_num = $(this).closest('tr').index();

     //var row_num = $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;

}
```

None seem to be working for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Which row number is clicked in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524661/jquery-which-row-number-is-clicked-in-table)

Comment: If you add your html and describe what you want to achieve (for example if a row is clicked it should get a different background) we can  help you better. Could you explain why the answers did not work for you?.

Comment: @IvanSivak, tried both the answers there...didnt work for me.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree....the answers are always returning 1 if i do a +1 or in other words 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Th problem you have is simply about the way that `click-row.bs.table` works, as far as `click-row.bs.table` is a table event, `this` keyword points to the table itself not to the row, so you just need to use the `$element` instead:

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
  var row_num = $element.index() + 1;
});
```

Comment: you missed the opening braces there `(` - for element

Answer (score -2):

Its better to use the data attribute with the index

> $element.data('index')

The method .index() will change if there are rows added for example by using expandRow

```js
// Open or close on click
$table.on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element, index) {
  if(!row.open){
    $table.bootstrapTable('expandRow', $element.data('index'));
  }
  else{
    $table.bootstrapTable('collapseRow', $element.data('index'));
  }
});
```