# Using jQuery to determine table row user clicking on - when table loaded dynamically via javaScript -?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal has been to report on the row number of an html table, that a user clicks on within that table - question is which tr element did the user click on?

I was able to do this when the information was hardcoded in the table by the html, using a previous posting [How to tell which row number is clicked in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524661/how-to-tell-which-row-number-is-clicked-in-a-table)

My **challenge** was that because the table was loaded dynamically via javascript, that I wasn't able to link things up properly between the html, the javascript and jQuery. When I clicked on a row in the dynamically generated table, I was not able to communicate I was doing that.

I'm working on a jQuery class and looking forward to understanding better how to think problems like this through. But it sure is nice to get help with things so that I have some good examples to work with during my learning.

Below is the code, **now working**, using the code that Ozan suggested.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Make Table</button>
<div id="container"></div>


<title>Board A</title>


 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <script src="mainTest.js"></script>


  </head>
   <center>
   <img src="MarmotNapping.jpg" alt="Marmot"

 height="150" width="400"
 >


  </center>



<body>

<p> Click in this line </p>



<script>
/*
// First Stackoverflow question I used
How to tell which row number is clicked in a table?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524661/how-to-tell-which-row-number-is-clicked-in-a-table
You can achieve this with delegated event handling.

Use jQuery's .on(eventName, selector, handler) method to attach the handler to an element you know will always be present, e.g. document.
*/

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820078/using-jquery-to-determine-table-row-user-clicking-on-when-table-loaded-dynamic

// begin new
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index(); //this is event.target, which is the clicked tr element in this case
  console.log(index);
   alert('0.You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("table").remove();
  var table = $("<table>").appendTo("#container");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("This is " + i + ". row.")).appendTo(table);

  }
});

// end new
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });


});

 $('#QuestionsAnswersTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('1.You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});

$('#QuestionsAnswersTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  alert('2.You clicked ' + row);
});



</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>*The question is not really clear. From what I understand you want to know which `tr` element was clicked and your table is loaded dynamically. Correct me in the comments if this was not what you mean.*</del>

You can achieve this with [delegated event handling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Use jQuery's [`.on(eventName, selector, handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach the handler to an element you know will always be present, e.g. `document`.

[jQuery Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```js
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index(); //this is event.target, which is the clicked tr element in this case
  console.log(index);
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("table").remove();
  var table = $("<table>").appendTo("#container");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("This is " + i + ". row.")).appendTo(table);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Make Table</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ozan - Thanks for letting me know that my question was unclear. Now I will try what you suggested. No matter what, I will attempt to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps. Formatting the code, clearly explaining the expected behavior and errors, and most of all providing a [MVCExample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with snippet, jsfiddle or equivalent would greatly improve your chances of getting a better answer.

Comment: I replaced the code and attempted to rewrite the question. I hope that the question is clear enough that someone else will be able to benefit from it. Now I will follow the link, to figure out what an MVCExample is!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Question is much more understandable now.